# Resize array function does not change memory location

Tags: c++

I found a function to resize an array and am having trouble understanding how it works (or if it's working properly).  For testing I set the "temp" array to a new value and "startCounter" does get assigned to that value, however the memory location for startCounter doesn't change.  Here is my code:

```
int * startCounter;


void resizeArray(int *&arraySent,int origSize,int newSize) {
    output << "&arraySent " << &arraySent << endl;
    output << "arraySent[0] " << arraySent[0] << endl;
    int* temp = new int[newSize];
    output << "&temp " << &temp << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<origSize; i++) {
        temp[i] = arraySent[i];
    }
    temp[0]=744;
    delete [] arraySent;
    arraySent = temp;
    output << "&arraySent " << &arraySent << endl;
}

//....

startCounter = new int [3];
startCounter[0]=345;
output << &startCounter << endl;
resizeArray(startCounter,3,10);
output << "startCounter[0]" << startCounter[0] << endl;
output << "&startCounter" << &startCounter << endl;
```

Here is the output I get from this:

```
    &startCounter 0x60fab8
    &arraySent 0x60fab8
    arraySent[0] 345
    &temp 0x82cfe54
    &arraySent 0x60fab8
    startCounter[0] 744
    &startCounter 0x60fab8
```

My question is, why does the memory location of startCounter not change from 0x60fab8 after deleting it and assigning it to the new "temp" array?  Shouldn't it now become 0x82cfe54?

P.S.  I understand about vectors and such but am mainly concerned with understanding how this particular function works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void resizeArray(int *&arraySent,int origSize,int newSize) {
    output << "&arraySent " << &arraySent << endl;
```

outputs the address of the pointer variable, not the address that it holds.

simply omit the address operator to get the (probably) intended effect

Answer (score 1):

`&startCounter` is the address of the pointer, not the address it points to. it's value won't change. simply use `startCounter`.